# Getting number of followers and "am I following" in a single SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm writing (as an exercise) a system where users get a list of vacations and can choose which vacations to "follow."

The UI for each vacation should convey two pieces of information:

1. How many users are currently following this vacation, and
2. Whether I (the logged-in user) am following this vacation.

For example, in this screenshot the vacation is followed by some other user, but not by me:

[image]

If, on the other hand, I *were* the one following this vacation, it would have looked like this:

[image]

(Note the darker color of the Follow button.)

I would like to obtain a list of all the vacations in the database, along with the above information for each vacation. To this end, my database (MySQL) contains three tables, `user`, `vacation` and `user_vacation`. To obtain the number of followers, I join `vacation` and `user_vacation` as follows:

```sql
SELECT
    vacation.*,
    COUNT(user_id) AS followers
FROM
    user_vacation
RIGHT JOIN `vacation` ON vacation_id = vacation.id
GROUP BY
    vacation.id;
```

However, I can't think of a way to add to the result set a boolean column that says whether a given user (the same one for all the rows in the result set) is following the vacation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate a boolean using:

```
SELECT v.*,
       COUNT(uv.user_id) AS followers,
       MAX( uv.user_id = ? ) as me_following
FROM vacation v LEFT JOIN
     user_vacation uv
     ON uv.vacation_id =  .id
GROUP BY v.id;
```

The `?` is intended to be a parameter that identifies the user you care about.

Note that I replaced the `RIGHT JOIN` with a `LEFT JOIN`.  That is usually easier to follow.

PS.  Now you've intrigued me with Coyhaique.

Comment: It’s a place I visited many years ago, as a boy. I guess it made quite an impression on me.

Comment: You need to replace `MAX( uv.user_id = ? )` with `IFNULL(MAX(uv.user_id = ?), 0)`